# Binary search algorithm / sorting for an ArrayList is Strings?

Tags: java

I have a question for one of the classes I am taking which is as follows.

> 6. You will need to create a method to search the ArrayList.  a.   Use a binary search algorithm for the search method which includes a sort
>      function. Do not use the Java.util.Arrays.binarySearch() method, but
>      write the binary search algorithm code. b.    Display the array element
>      and the array index.

I am having real trouble finding an answer online (been looking for a couple hours now).

I understand how a binary search works but not when it comes to stings as too my understanding an Array needs to be sorted before it can be binary searched, but how do you do this without using Array.sort function.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to tackle this problem?

Cheers!

Here is the code: The binarySearch code is downt he very bottom, and the search part where i'm calling is is in the middle when "3" is pressed.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class BirdArrayList {

    static ArrayList<String> birdList = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    static String response;
    static int birdIndex = -1;

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

        birdList.add("Crow");  //adding five initial birds to the birdList ArrayList
        birdList.add("Magpie");
        birdList.add("Dove");
        birdList.add("Finch");
        birdList.add("Kookaburra");


        while (!"5".equals(response))
        {
            response =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number for what you wish to do \n"
                    + " 1 \t ADD a bird to the list \n"
                    + " 2 \t REMOVE a bird from the list \n"
                    + " 3 \t SEARCH for a bird in the list \n"
                    + " 4 \t DISPLAY the list of birds \n"
                    + " 5 \t QUIT the program"); // Main screen of the program, formatted nicely

            if(response.equals("1")) // Add a bird
            {
                addEntry();
            }

            if(response.equals("2"))//Remove a bird from the list
            {
                deleteEntry();
            }

            if(response.equals("3"))//Search for a bird
            {
                response =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a bird name to SEARCH for it \n and see if it is on the list!");
                int birdIndex = (binarySearch(birdList, response));
                if(birdIndex >=0)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The bird name " + response + " was on the list "
                            + "\nin Array Index ("+birdIndex+")");
                }
            }


            if(response.equals("4"))  // Displays the array
            {
                displayArray();
            }
            if(response.equals("5")) // Quit the program
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void addEntry()
    {
        response =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a bird name to ADD it to the list"); 
        birdList.add(response); // adds the response to the birdList in the next Array position
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response + " added!"); // Shows bird name added
         displayArray();
    }

    public static void deleteEntry()
    {
        response =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a bird name to REMOVE it from the list");
        boolean isRemoved = false;
        for(int i=0;i<birdList.size();i++)
        {
            if(birdList.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(response))
            {
                birdList.remove(i);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response + " removed!");
                isRemoved = true;
            }

        }
        if(isRemoved == false)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The bird you tried to remove was not on the list");
        }
        displayArray();

        /* How I was originally going to do it before I re-read the requirements.
        /*if(birdList.contains(response))
        {
            birdList.remove(response);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response + " removed!");
        }
        else
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The bird you tried to remove was not on the list");
        }*/
    }
    public static void displayArray()
    {
        String displayList = "";
        int tempCounter = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<birdList.size();i++) //Display the ArrayList 
        {
            String tempBird = birdList.get(i); //Makes tempBird more workable in the displayList formula 2 lines down
            tempCounter++; // shows a nuber before the bird in the list
            displayList += tempCounter + ".   " + tempBird + "\n";   //formatting nicely    
        }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, displayList); //Displays the list

    }

    public static int binarySearch(List<String> birdList, String response)
    {
        int low = 0;
        int high = birdList.size();
        int mid = (low + high)/2;



        while(low<high && !birdList.get(mid).equalsIgnoreCase(response))
        {
            if (birdList.get(mid).equalsIgnoreCase(response)) 
            {
                low = mid + 1;
            } 
            else 
            {
                high = mid - 1;
            }

            mid = (low + high) / 2;

            if (low > high) {
                birdIndex = mid;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("low "+low+"\nhigh " + high + "\nmid " +mid+ "\nBI " +birdIndex);
        birdIndex = mid;
        return birdIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize this is a school assignment, but sorting an array to do a binary search is a terribly inefficient way of finding an element. Just saying.

Comment: To sort an array, you will pass each element (at least once) to compare it to others. If you really want to have your element, then you could just do a simple loop and it will give you the element. However, that is not the assignment. I think you should read a bit about how to use the Comparator interface and how to implement it. .equals() is pretty much useless in binary search.

Comment: @shmosel yeh, It definitely feels that way, but gotta do it haha.

Comment: @Wietlol Yep I am planning on putting this project aside for the moment and starting a fresh one that is purely to get this problem sorted then apply its concept back into my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually sort the array using any sort of algorithm you wish, using the compareTo(String otherString) method to see if another string is "less than" or "greater than" another.

If you were to use a selection sort algorithm, the code would look something like this:

```
// will iterate throughout the entire list to sort
for (int i = 0; i < birdList.size() - 1; i++) { 
      int lowestVal = i;

      // will iterate through list to find next smallest value
      for (int j = i + 1; j < birdList.size(); j++) {
           if (birdList.get(j).compareTo(birdList.get(lowestVal)) < 0)
               lowestVal = j; // found new minimum value
   }

   // swap out the next lowest value with the next value in the list
   String temp = birdList.get(i);
   birdList.set(i, birdList.get(lowestVal));
   birdList.set(lowestVal, temp);
}
```

EDIT: Just a bit more information. The compareTo method is part of the Comparable interface which the String class happens to implement. This allows you to basically compare strings and sort them this way.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works in sorting the list in alphabetical order with my current set up, now to get the binary search part working.